# Fetch all Posts where logged in user has commented

Tags: sql

I'm not good at sql queries so the question is:

How do I list all the Posts where logged in user has left the comment?

I guess it's kinda obvious that redundancy is unwanted in case user posted multiple comments to the same Post.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be simple since comments are stored with a user_id if they are created by a logged in user and if not then its set to false so all you need to do is select the post id from comments that are made by user_id bigger the zero, something like this:

```
function get_posts_with_loogedin_user_comments(){
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT  comment_post_ID
            FROM  $wpdb->comments
            WHERE  user_id > 0
            ";
    $post_ids = $wpdb->get_col($sql);
    if ($post_ids)
        return $post_ids;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! The only thing that I changed is sql WHERE clause because it actually needs to be compared to logged in user ID. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Bainternet, can you please paste the code after changes? I am a new bee to Wordpress. Having hard time to achieve this.

Comment: @Nilanchala sorry but the comment above yours was addressed to me and not by me so i have no idea what was the change. i can only assume that he changed `user_id > 0` to `user_id = 'x'` where X is the actual user ID